# Page reload sometimes doesn't show a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

so right now I'm making a dashboard side-menu that collapse-able and reopen-able. Everything works great, except for one issue. Let's say I collapsed my side-menu, and then start pressing the refresh page over and over, at a speed of about 1 click/sec. About 2/10 of those page reloads will not show up with the button that is supposed to be there. Here's what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#home").click(function () {
        "use strict";
        $.cookie('open', false);
        $(this).hide();
        $("#home2").show();
        $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
        $(".content").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 200, function () {});
        $(".content").animate({width: "100%"}, 200, function () {});
    });

    $("#home2").click(function () {
        "use strict";
        $.cookie('open', true);
        $(this).hide();
        $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
        $("#home").show();
        $(".content").animate({marginLeft: "220px"}, 200, function () {});
        $(".content").animate({width: "100%"}, 200, function () {});
    });

    if ($.cookie('open') === 'false') {

        $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
        $(".content").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 1, function () {});
        $(".content").animate({width: "100%"}, 1, function () {});
        $.cookie('open', false);
        $("#home").hide();
        $("#home2").show();
    }
});
```

I used cookies to get the state of whether the sidebar menu was up.  When the cookie open == false, then the sidebar is closed, and when cookie open == true, then it is opened.

To give more detail, the ID "home2" is the one that is not showing up some of the times.

Whenever I do a page reload, there's a couple of milliseconds where I can see the

```
    $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
    $(".content").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 1, function () {});
    $(".content").animate({width: "100%"}, 1, function () {});
```

stuff doing its work. Whenever that happens, the button will show up. But sometimes on the page reloads, the page doesn't do this and it just reloads lightning fast where I can't see the previously mentioned code doing its job; this is when the #home2 button decides not to pop up, which leads me to believe that the stuff in statement is not being performed.

This is such a bizarre problem and I have no idea why it's behaving like this..

EDIT: Changed if statement around to:

```
if ($.cookie('open') === 'false') {
    $("#home2").show();
    $("#home").hide();
    $(".content").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 1, function () {});
    $(".content").animate({width: "100%"}, 1, function () {});
    $.cookie('open', false);
    $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
}
```

Still having same problem.

Comment: You should probably consider carefully the animations and if they should be chained or otherwise given a definitive execution sequence. - on the `.content` you have two of those; can it be combined to one etc.

Comment: Are those duration settings of 1 on the `.content` needed or do you really just want CSS to set those values here? 1 is pretty short at 1 millisecond - it probably takes longer just to set up the timer etc. on each of those

Comment: One other option is to do this later in the page cycle by using `$(window).load(function(){
  //my code here
});` instead of the document ready; what does that do here?  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I used one millisecond because if I don't, the default time is really slow, and I need it to hide the sidebar ASAP on the page reload.

Comment: Just wanted to add: I used $(window).load(function(){//stuff }); and I have not yet had a problem. Will keep testing.

Comment: I put the load in as an answer so we can track the comments/success on that specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do this later in the page cycle by using

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    //my code here 
});
```

instead of the document ready; what does that do here? [api.jquery.com/ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

Answer (score 0):

Possible chances may be slow net connectivity.

Or else script is not loaded properly at time of refresh.

Cache may also become obstacle for the given problem.

Comment: I know my net connectivity is more than fine. So how could I properly load it at refresh or how can I solve the cache issue?

Comment: which server are you using? Can you send the image of NETWORK tab in inspect element

Comment: I'm currently using Apache with WAMP. Here's the network tab: http://i.imgur.com/dTBWDpP.png

Comment: as per your image, it looks that everything is working pretty cool.

At time of generating this image was there a problem with loading?

Comment: I think that the solution Mark provided worked out. Thank you for your help though!